# Horizontal scrolling navbar bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, navbar, horizontal-scrolling

I have a navbar on the right side of my website, but if i resize the screen like a tablet screen, the navbar goes on 2 rows.

My navbar html code is basic:

```
<div class="nav_div col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-7"> 
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-nav" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-nav">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
                <li data-menuanchor="blablab" class="active"><a href="#blablab">blablab</a></li>
                <li data-menuanchor="blablab"><a href="#blablab">blablab</a></li>
                <li data-menuanchor="blablab"><a href="#blablab">blablab</a></li>
                <li data-menuanchor="blablab"><a href="#blablab">blablab</a></li>
                <li data-menuanchor="blablab"><a href="#blablab">blablab</a></li>
                <li data-menuanchor="blablab"><a href="#blablab">blablab</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
          </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>    
    </div>
```

[image]

I search to have an auto horizontal scrolling bar where the active tab is in the middle.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this: `<div class="nav_div col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-7"></div>`
your `col-sm-7` is not large enough to hold your content when the view-port resizes so it pushes the content to a new row.

You can change it to something like this `<div class="nav_div col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">` as an easy clean solution.

**Two solutions with Demos:**

```
<div class="nav_div col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9"> 
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-nav" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-nav">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
                <li data-menuanchor="blablab" class="active"><a href="#blablab">blablab</a></li>
                <li data-menuanchor="blablab"><a href="#blablab">blablab</a></li>
                <li data-menuanchor="blablab"><a href="#blablab">blablab</a></li>
                <li data-menuanchor="blablab"><a href="#blablab">blablab</a></li>
                <li data-menuanchor="blablab"><a href="#blablab">blablab</a></li>
                <li data-menuanchor="blablab"><a href="#blablab">blablab</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
          </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>    
    </div>
```

[CODEPEN DEMO 1](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/LpgLVO)

**OR**

You can manipulate the padding of your nav links in CSS, this allows you to still use `<div class="nav_div col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-7"></div>` without it breaking to a new row on screen resize.

```
.navbar-nav > li > a{
   line-height: 50px;
   padding: 0 5px;
}
```

[CODEPEN DEMO 2](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/EVdXPm)

IF you want vertical scrolling youll need to *decrease* the size of your columns, however this is not a good way to structure a nav if you're using bootstrap.

```
<div class="nav_div col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-3"> 
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
                <li data-menuanchor="blablab" class="active"><a href="#blablab">blablab</a></li>
                <li data-menuanchor="blablab"><a href="#blablab">blablab</a></li>
                <li data-menuanchor="blablab"><a href="#blablab">blablab</a></li>
                <li data-menuanchor="blablab"><a href="#blablab">blablab</a></li>
                <li data-menuanchor="blablab"><a href="#blablab">blablab</a></li>
                <li data-menuanchor="blablab"><a href="#blablab">blablab</a></li>
              </ul>
          </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>    
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar{
   max-height: 40px;
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

[CODEPEN DEMO 3](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/pjxwWb/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but you don't understand what i search to do. O search to have a vertical scrolling. then if the windows is too small, the user can scroll on the navbar, and it still in one row

Comment: if you want vertical scrolling then why do you have the navbar in a collapse lol

Comment: Its for xs device (phone), and vetical is for tablet or mini laptop

Comment: I updated my answer, look at bottom, unfortunately what you're trying to do is inefficient within bootstrap and I don't recommend it.

Comment: ok, thanks, in horizontal it's wil be better. How can i use a js script fo have the active tab in the middle ?

Comment: You can give it a bootstrap class off ``active``, for example ``<li class="active">``.

Comment: I know, what i search to have it's, if the last tab is active, we can see it in the navbar. beacuse if the windows is too small, i only have the 3 first tab